# MVC 4 clientside validation for textbox with dynamically swtichable datatype

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, client

I am Novices to MVC 4.
I have one dynamically generated textbox;  In my form there is also option to choose the data-type of this textbox like numeric, alphanumeric, integer or date.  Therefore, I will only know the excepted data-type of the textbox on runtime.
So, is there any way to implement client side validation with MVC UnobtrusiveJavaScript technique?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Not sure if it's possible to do it client side without writing a lot of javascript. If server side validation suits you, it can be done by implementing IValidatableObject in your view model in order to check your input according to selected type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the data-type is set client side, set the value of a hidden field in your model. Your controller can validate the input based on which data type it gets from the model. If you have lots of text boxes on the page, this would get messy. I would go with Réda Mattar's suggestion then.